# How to display content and modules based on visitor's location?

Tags: extensions, module-display

A client has content (i.e. articles and modules) which they wish to be displayed to a web site visitor based on their location (e.g. if visitor is in 'City A' show articles and modules for 'City A' and if client is in 'City B' show content and modules for 'City B').

How can this be accomplished in each of the following 2 scenarios

1. Non-registered users based on IP address; and
2. Registered users based on their user profile postal or zip code?

Does this require custom code or are there any specific extensions which available which can address the above requirements?

Comment: Hi, I think this extension can help you with that: http://www.metamodpro.com/chameleon/shop17

Comment: Would No Numbers [Advanced Module Manager](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager#free-vs-pro)  be any good for this?

Comment: Advanced Module Manager does looking promising, but I am hoping for a more in-depth explanation.  This does help, though, so thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Advanced Module Manager** has a thoughtful set of filters to show modules according several conditions. It can certainly help to dynamically show modules by country, region or state.

You can test the Free version to better know how it works. However, **Geolocating** (to assign modules by country, region or state) is a [PRO feature](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager#free-vs-pro). Also, the PRO version allows to integrate *Extra fields* or *Custom PHP* from the extended User Profile.

- Concerning to Articles, Joomla does not have general Geolocation feature. Then, components cannot support it (unless they are built it for this specific purpouse). As a solution, Nonumber's Advanced Module Manager can be a gateway to display articles through modules. For example, [Article Placed Anywhere](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/article-placed-anywhere) module can help to replace the single article view. CON: Menu item options to configure component views are not going to be available for geolocation, only modules are going to be geolocated.